# LIN transceiver instability problem

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, transceiver, lin

I'm using the [MCP2021A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002298C.pdf) for my project. In this component, there is a voltage regulator but I have no use for it. They usually power microcontroller like the PIC18F2455 but I'm using a Raspberry Pi which consumes too much current.

If I don't use this regulator, I have no output on my LIN BUS.

Can someone explain to me how it works so I can find a solution ?

Schematic:

[image]

I just connected pin 3 of IC (MCP2021A) to an unused Arduino so I can have VREG_OK which I don't have if it's floating.

Comment: The MCP2021A is the only chip I had an unlimited supply of, this is why I choose it.

Comment: There's nothing to do with the internal regulator output, and you don't have to use it. `If I don't use this Regulator I have no output on my LIN BUS.` What do you mean? Did you mean "left floating" by "not using"? The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, If I left it floating it's not working.
I'm doing everything so it enters operation mod but if i disconnect Vreg from the Arduino that I power (just so it works, i don't need an arduino), it stops working. I think it's VREG_OK  that goes to 0

Comment: Disconnect from Arduino? In the question, you said that you are using an RPi. Anyway, you'd better post a schematic/connection diagram. It'd help us a lot.

Comment: I just added a schematic, it should be more comprehensive. The arduino is just here so Vreg is not floating

Comment: @Graggon:  That is **not** a schematic diagram.  It is a wiring diagram.  Anyone who wants to help you will have to first translate it to a schematic diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it's VREG_OK that goes to 0

The problem is about the Vreg pin, but not about drawing a current from that pin. VREG_OK does not indicate if the Vreg pin is floating. Vreg is the output voltage of an on-chip regulator and the chip uses this voltage for the internals *(look at the block diagram at p.2)*. It's not a must that you should draw current from that voltage.

However, **this pin requires a bypass capacitor** for stability *(First sentence at p.9)*:

[image]
*Img Src: Datasheet, p.19.*

So, if you connect a low-ESR capacitor with a capacitance of at least 10uF then everything will be fine.

> but if i disconnect Vreg from the Arduino that I power (just so it works, i don't need an arduino), it stops working. ... The arduino is just here so Vreg is not floating

Arduino's input line bypass capacitors are fixing the instability here :)

Comment: So everything makes sense now! Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. Çok teşekkür ederim :)

Comment: @Graggon rica ederim :)